# How can I count features in each column of my dataframe ?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Data frame with multiple columns and with only 1 and 0 values.

It looks like this :

time A B C D

xxxx 0 0 0 0

xxxx 0 1 0 1

xxxx 0 0 0 1

I would like to count, how many time I have 1 (corresponding to errors) in a day. 
I see how to do it with one column :

```
  errors = (df.filter('A=1')
              .select(to_date(df.time).alias('day'),df.A)
              .groupBy('day')
              .count()
               )
```

This is getting me the good results for one column, although it doesn't give me 0 when there is no error in a day (and i would like to get all days, with 0 if there is no error).

I'm stuck in trying to parse it to all columns. 
I would like also to avoid (if possible) to do it for each column and then join because I have 8 columns.

Any help ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a minute and read this tutorial for better questions, especially examples about good and bad titles: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - everything else looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so here you go. I've just simplified the date parsing step considering the low quality of your sample but the idea is here.

So considering the following DataFrame `df` :

```
+----+---+---+---+---+
|time|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+----+---+---+---+---+
|xxxx|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|xxxx|  0|  1|  0|  1|
|xxxx|  0|  0|  0|  1|
+----+---+---+---+---+
```

You'll just need to use the aggregation function `sum` on each column as followed :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.groupBy('time') \
  .agg(F.sum('A').alias("A"),F.sum('B').alias("B"),F.sum('C').alias("C"),F.sum('D').alias("D")) \
  .show()

# +----+---+---+---+---+
# |time|  A|  B|  C|  D|
# +----+---+---+---+---+
# |xxxx|  0|  1|  0|  2|
# +----+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It is exactly what I was looking for, I don't know why I didn't think of sum().